# How to get the new value in ResizeObzerver

Tags: javascript, getvalue, resize-observer

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="scrollable scrollable-y" id="scroll">
<ul class="chatlist contacts-container" id="contacts" data-autonomous="1">
  <a class="chatlist-chat rp" data-peer-id="100201777">
  <a class="chatlist-chat rp" data-peer-id="100201778">
  <a class="chatlist-chat rp" data-peer-id="100201779">
</ul>
<div>
```

The div with id "scroll" is scrollable and this belongs to telegram web contacts. Every "a" element is a contact and when we scroll through div, we get and contacts and more a's are fetched from server dynamically. When I use from script below, I realize that scrooHeight of ul child and thus scrollable div increases.

```
const container = $("#scroll");
const observer = new ResizeObserver(function() {
console.log('New scrollHeight', container[0].scrollHeight);});

container.children().each(function(index, child) {
observer.observe(child);})
```

My question is how do I get NEW value? something like

```
observer.container[0].scrollHeight.get();
```

Comment: scroll is not a resize event and will not trigger the observer

Comment: ok, I know, but because it fetches the contacts from server, the new ones will be added to ul list and size of it as a child in script increases. So I can see the result of script. it has new result for ul.

Comment: so you need the new value for the scroll offset,  the container or the child contentRect? if your new a elements resize the container, why do you observe the children? doing so with only the container would suffice

Comment: 1. New value for childs scrollHeight or actually ul scrollheight, not for its contentRect. It's easy to get. I need to get new value for ul's scrollHeight as a child of container.
2. container's scrollHeight follows child's scrollHeight and its apparently unchanged when I use e.g. console.log. But if stop script running and start it again, I can see new value explicitly by console.log but I want see and GET it without stopping script.

Comment: New a elements resize ul not container. We can only get scrollHeight of ul and consequently container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const container = $("#contacts")[0];
const div = document.getElementsByClassName("scrollable scrollable-y")[1];

let resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
        
        for (entry of entries) {
        console.log('New scrollHeight is: ', entries[0].contentRect.height);
}});

resizeObserver.observe(container);
```

By this script, you will see several result all of them are equal and the required new value of new scrollHeight . Thanks to @zerski to inspire me.